# iso-8859-1 encode string to utf-8 in java

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

[image]

Does anyone know how to convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8?  I have researched in many websites and blogs, I have read 100 posts in StackOverflow, but nothing has helped me.  So I am writing this.

In an HTML text area, I am inserting `ŁACZĄCY`.  When coming to Java, it is coming as `&#321;ACZ&#260;CY`.  How to convert it back to the origin string?  The server is an IBM websphere.

Can anybody please help me to resolve the issue?

I have searched online converters from Latin (ISO-8859-1) to UTF-8, they are showing the exact conversion.

When I enter `&#321;ACZ&#260;CY` and click on Latin to UTF, it shows `ŁACZĄCY`.

http://site112.com/converter-latin-utf

Please help me resolve this issue.  If you want any other details, please ask me.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to get as a result? ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 are two different character encodings. Do you understand how [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) works?

Comment: Good article: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: What is the “origin string” and how is it different from the "ŁACZĄCY" text you mention in points 1 and 2 of your first paragraph?

Comment: @VGR the original string is "ŁACZĄCY" and the string i am getting i have attached a picture.in java i am doing request.getParameter and i am getting different from original one i have attached the screenshot

Comment: @jesper i know how charcter encoding works in java. the 2nd point in my question has same original string because stack over flow converted it into uTF-8 please check my screenshot i have attached and please reply back on this thanks.

Comment: What I see in your screenshot is **not** UTF-8 encoding, but HTML escaping. Whoever made that website does not understand what UTF-8 is...

Comment: That converter site is *broken and wrong.*  "&#321;ACZ&#260;CY" has nothing to do with UTF-8.  It’s just an HTML escaping of "ŁACZĄCY", and the site is **lying** when it claims that that text is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @jesper i am not saying it as utf-8 encoding the application server converting the UTF-8 string (ŁACZĄCY) which is given in html form to the string which u r saying html escaping how to get back the original string which user entered insetad of this html escaping string?

Comment: @Jesper because in database it is saving as HTML escaping string how to save original one please advice me some solution

Comment: Forget about UTF-8, because this has nothing to do with UTF-8. You need to find an HTML unescaping utility class or method.

Comment: Thanks for your help i wil try that

Comment: When a browser submits an HTML5 (not HTML4) webform to an HTTP server, the HTML5 spec (section 4.10.22.7) dictates that non-ASCII characters be encoded in `&#xxxx;` format if the webform is submitted in `multipart/form-data` format and the characters do not exist in the charset selected for the submission, whether that be explicit by the webform itself or the charset used by the HTML doc. It sounds like your server does not handle that aspect of HTML5 processing.

Comment: You will have to either 1) decode the characters manually in your server code (if you include an `<input type="hidden" name="_charset_">` element in your HTML5 webform, the server will receive the actual charset that the browser selects, which may help you when decoding data), or 2) fix your webform to use a different charset (like UTF-8) that supports the characters you want to send.  `Ł` and `Ą` do not exist in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for replying yeah my server is not handling i found html unescape charcters and it is working from form to java but can anybody suggest how to save greek or polish charcters in db and get back the same and display in browser?

Comment: @Jesper thanks the html unescape utility worked but in db it is saving with question marks or rectangle boxes and while retrieving i am getting same rectangle boxes do you have any solution on this?

Comment: That is most likely a character encoding problem. For that you need to carefully check what happens to the data in each step, for example: is the right encoding used when writing to or reading from the db, and when displaying the data on screen, etc. It's hard to tell where the problem is, it can be in a number of places, from the database settings to your code...

Comment: @Jesper now i have changed the jsp characterset encoding to UTF-8 and now i am receving string as "ÅACZÄCY" and while i am retrieving i am getting as �?ACZ�?CY where is the mistake i am doing ??

Comment: @RemyLebeau i have changed the charset to utf-8 in jsp and server but while i am retrieving it in java request.getparameter("text") giving ÅACZÄCY and i am saving it in DB while reterving i am getting it as �?ACZ�?CY this

Comment: @AviNash there are multiple steps involved and they are clearly not agreeing on a charset to use. Data that is encoded in one charset, like UTF-8, is being interpreted in another charset, like Latin. You need to fix that at every step. Make sure the webform data is received correctly. Make sure the DB data is stored correctly. Make sure it is retrieved correctly. You are muttling this question with too many things. Break up the steps and ask separate questions for each one.

Comment: ŁĄCZĄCY is ISO-8859-2 orin worst case it might be windows-1250, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250